# Count words in List

Tags: scala

I have a List of Strings :

```
 val file: List[String] = List("a1,a,b", "a1,c,b", "a2,a,d,e")
```

and I'm attempting to count the number of times each word occurs in the String associated with the excluding the first element in csv String.

So above List should be converted to :

```
List("a1,1,2,1,0,0", "a2,1,0,0,1,1")    

as for "a1" a occurs once, b occurs twice , c occurs once , d occurs 0 times, e occurs 0 times
for "a2" a occurs once, b 0 times , c 0 times , d occurs once, e occurs once
```

Here is what I have so far :

```
 def getTail[T](l : List[T]) = l match {
        case h::t => t
    }                                             //> getTail: [T](l: List[T])List[T]

    def getHead[T](l : List[T]) = l match {
        case h::t => h
    }                                             //> getHead: [T](l: List[T])T

    val arr = file.map(m => (getHead(m.split(",").toList) , getTail(m.split(",").toList)))
                                                  //> arr  : List[(String, List[String])] = List((a1,List(a, b)), (a1,List(c, b)),
                                                  //|  (a2,List(a, d, e)))

    val g = arr.groupBy(_._1)                     //> g  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(String, List[String])]] = M
                                                  //| ap(a1 -> List((a1,List(a, b)), (a1,List(c, b))), a2 -> List((a2,List(a, d, e
                                                  //| ))))
    val keysRemoved = g.mapValues(v => v.map (v2 => v2._2).flatten)
                                                  //> keysRemoved  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(a1 
                                                  //| -> List(a, b, c, b), a2 -> List(a, d, e))
    val associateOne = keysRemoved.mapValues(v => v.map(m => (m , 1)))

val counted = keysRemoved.mapValues(v => v.map(m => (m , 1)))
                                              //> counted  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(String, Int)]] = Map(
                                              //| a1 -> List((a,1), (b,1), (c,1), (b,1)), a2 -> List((a,1), (d,1), (e,1)))
```

But I'm unsure how to count each element of the List and also how to count return 0 for words that are not contained in the List ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val file: List[String] = List("a1,a,b", "a1,c,b", "a2,a,d,e")
val splitCsvs = file.map { line =>
  val split = line.split(",")   // split up the csv line
  split.head -> split.tail      // separate the key from the words
}
val collapsed = splitCsvs.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.flatMap(_._2)) // group by key
val allWords = collapsed.flatMap(_._2).toVector.distinct.sorted // get all unique words

val result = collapsed.map {
  case (head, tail) =>
    val counts = tail.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).withDefaultValue(0) // count
    (head +: allWords.map(counts)).mkString(",") // make counts string, with the key
}

result.foreach(println)
```

prints:

```
a1,1,2,1,0,0
a2,1,0,0,1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't pretend it's the easiest solution, but it was fun to code. Great question.

```
  val file: List[String] = List("a1,a,b", "a1,c,b", "a2,a,d,e")
                                                  //> file  : List[String] = List(a1,a,b, a1,c,b, a2,a,d,e)
  val xs = file.map(_.split(',').toList)          //> xs  : List[List[String]] = List(List(a1, a, b), List(a1, c, b), List(a2, a, 
                                                  //| d, e))
  val (hs, ts) = xs.unzip { case(h::t) => (h, t) }//> hs  : List[String] = List(a1, a1, a2)
                                                  //| ts  : List[List[String]] = List(List(a, b), List(c, b), List(a, d, e))
  val ks = hs.distinct                            //> ks  : List[String] = List(a1, a2)
  val vs = ts.flatten.distinct                    //> vs  : List[String] = List(a, b, c, d, e)

  val matrix =
    xs.map { case(h::t) => h -> t.map(_ -> 1) }
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .mapValues(_.flatMap(_._2)
                  .groupBy(_._1)
                  .mapValues(_.map(_._2)
                              .reduce(_ + _))
                  .withDefaultValue(0))           //> matrix  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.M
                                                  //| ap[String,Int]] = Map(a1 -> Map(b -> 2, a -> 1, c -> 1), a2 -> Map(e -> 1, d
                                                  //|  -> 1, a -> 1))
  ks.map { k => (k::vs.map(matrix(k))).mkString(",") }
                                                  //> res0: List[String] = List(a1,1,2,1,0,0, a2,1,0,0,1,1)
```